# Não consigo mudar o valor de um input em React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou ajudando um amigo com um projeto, e preciso que um campo de input tenha um valor padrão, que no caso é um ID, já tentei colocar "value" e "defaultValue", porém ele não aceita aquele valor para fazer o submit, é como se ele só aceitasse um valor que o usuário DIGITOU. Já tentei até mesmo inserir um número inteiro VÁLIDO com um botão ou algo do tipo, com: "document.getElementById("comunidade").value = 1;"

Porém, sem sucesso, ele não reconhece que tem um dado ali, só reconhece o que o usuário digitar no input. Por exemplo, se eu for no input e digitar o número um, ele da o submit.

```
function onChange(ev) {
    const { name, value } = ev.target;
    setComunidade(values.id)
    setValues({ ...values, [name]: value });   
      
}

function onSubmit(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();   
    const method = 'put';
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/topico/';  
    axios[method](url, values)
    history.push('/comunidades');    
 }

...

<Form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
...
<Input type="text" id="comunidade" name="comunidade" onChange={onChange} />
...
<Form/>
```

Answer (score -2):

Você não deveria alterar valores de um input no `react` da forma padrão do `javascript`.

pois o `react` trabalha em um modo reativo ou seja primeiro há uma alteração no código `javascript` e depois é apresentado em tela.

Afins de conhecimento, deixei um exemplo de como é a forma mais comum usada para pegar valores de um input e usa-los na função de submit.

```js
  function App() {
    const [comunidade, setComunidade] = React.useState("");

    function handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log("valor do input:" + comunidade);
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Seu formulário</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="comunidade"
            name="comunidade"
            onChange={(e) => setComunidade(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button>enviar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```